# "Online Chinese course" or "Chinese online course"?

Tags: meaning, expressions

I intend to teach Chinese online. But I was just wondering which course title would be appropriate and if there's any difference:

> Online Chinese course
>   Chinese online course

They sound a bit different, but what's the difference specifically? In this case, which term should I use for the course title?

Thank you.

Comment: I would generally avoid the word "course" in a course title.  Consider that this is "English Language & Usage," not "English Language & Usage Website"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the basic difference is:

When you say *Online Chinese course*, it does mean that it's an online course about the Chinese language, specifically.

On the other hand, *Chinese online course* could mean that the mode of instruction of the online course is Chinese (it's taught in Chinese), but it doesn't really say that it teaches Chinese specifically.

I wish I could provide you a more concrete answer, but this is what I could come up with off the top of my head!

Answer (score 0):

I admire and congratulate you on your project.  I wish you the best of luck and success.   (You'll need the first, then the second will happen.)

A good rule to follow is, the adjective comes before the word it modifies:

[Online Chinese] course.
Online [Chinese course].

Both could mean the same thing, bit I go with Manish Giri.